# calculate the amount spend based on every month which depends on another column value ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get the amount spent on each type ID based on the month column

Dataset :

```
ID  TYPE_ID Month_year  Amount
100 1   jun_2019    20
100 1   jul_2019    30
100 2   jun_2019    10
200 1   jun_2019    50
200 1   jun_2019    30
100 2   jul_2019    20
200 2   jun_2019    40
200 2   jul_2019    10
200 2   jun_2019    20
200 1   jul_2019    30
100 1   jul_2019    10
```

Output :
Based on every type ID, I want to calculate the spend depending on the month . The column value  **TYPEID_1_jun2019** tells me the no of transactions done in that particular month. **Amount_type1_jun2019** tells me the total amount spend in every month based on my type ID.

```
ID  TYPEID_1_jun2019    Amount_type1_jun2019    TYPEID_1_jul2019    Amount_type1_jul2019    TYPEID_2_jun2019    Amount_type2_jun2019    TYPEID_2_jul2019    Amount_type2_jul2019
100 1   20  2   40  1   10  1   20
200 1   80  1   30  2   60  1   10
```

**EDIT :  I also want to calculate the average monthly spent for every ID**

Output : Also include these columns,

```
ID      Average_type1_jul2019   Average_type1_jun2019

100              20                        10
```

**The formula I used to calculate the average is  `amount spent in july with type ID 1 divided by the total months`.**

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Do you want change `.agg({'Amount':'sum', 'type':'size'})` to `agg(Amount=('Amount','sum'),
             Average=('Amount','mean'),
             type=('type','size'))` ? Only pandas 0.24+ is necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert `Month_year` to datetimes for correct order, then create helper column `type` and aggregate `sum` with `size`, reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last flatten `MultiIndex` with datetimes to original format:

```
df['Month_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month_year'], format='%b_%Y')
df1 = (df.assign(type=df['TYPE_ID']).groupby(['ID','Month_year','TYPE_ID'])
        .agg({'Amount':'sum', 'type':'size'})
        .unstack([1,2])
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=[1,2]))

df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[2]}_{x[1].strftime("%b_%Y")}')
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
    ID  Amount_1_Jun_2019  type_1_Jun_2019  Amount_2_Jun_2019  \
0  100                 20                1                 10   
1  200                 80                2                 60   

   type_2_Jun_2019  Amount_1_Jul_2019  type_1_Jul_2019  Amount_2_Jul_2019  \
0                1                 40                2                 20   
1                2                 30                1                 10   

   type_2_Jul_2019  
0                1  
1                1
```

EDIT:

```
#removed sorting anf flatteting MultiIndex
df['Month_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month_year'], format='%b_%Y')
df1 = (df.assign(type=df['TYPE_ID']).groupby(['ID','Month_year','TYPE_ID'])
        .agg({'Amount':'sum', 'type':'size'})
        .unstack([1,2]))
print (df1)
               Amount                          type                 
Month_year 2019-06-01     2019-07-01     2019-06-01    2019-07-01   
TYPE_ID             1   2          1   2          1  2          1  2
ID                                                                  
100                20  10         40  20          1  1          2  1
200                80  60         30  10          2  2          1  1
```

---

```
#get number of unique mmonth_year per ID and type and divided by Amount
df2 = df.groupby(['ID','TYPE_ID'])['Month_year'].nunique().unstack()
df3 = df1.xs('Amount', axis=1, level=0).div(df2, level=1)
#added top level Average
df3.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Average', a, b) for a, b in df3.columns])
print (df3)
       Average                       
    2019-06-01       2019-07-01      
             1     2          1     2
ID                                   
100       10.0   5.0       20.0  10.0
200       40.0  30.0       15.0   5.0
```

---

```
#join together, sorting and flatten MultiIndex
df5 = pd.concat([df1, df3],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=[1,2])
df5.columns = df5.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[2]}_{x[1].strftime("%b_%Y")}')
df5 = df5.reset_index()
print (df5)
    ID  Amount_1_Jun_2019  Average_1_Jun_2019  type_1_Jun_2019  \
0  100                 20                10.0                1   
1  200                 80                40.0                2   

   Amount_2_Jun_2019  Average_2_Jun_2019  type_2_Jun_2019  Amount_1_Jul_2019  \
0                 10                 5.0                1                 40   
1                 60                30.0                2                 30   

   Average_1_Jul_2019  type_1_Jul_2019  Amount_2_Jul_2019  Average_2_Jul_2019  \
0                20.0                2                 20                10.0   
1                15.0                1                 10                 5.0   

   type_2_Jul_2019  
0                1  
1                1
```

Comment: I have edited my question a bit, can you also get me the average ? @jezrael

Comment: mean will actually take into consideration the total no of amounts in that month..I want only the total months
mean = sum of  amount in that month(typeID =1)/ total no of observations in that month(typeID = 1)
.....required = sum of amount in that month(typeID =1) / total no of months (viz = 2)

Comment: if its not possible to include the average in the same dataframe, then we can go with a new dataframe as well

Comment: Mean wont work there.. as per the formula I mentioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206411/discussion-between-jezrael-and-pylearner).

Comment: HI can you please help out on this ..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738169/extract-values-from-a-column-and-create-another-data-frame-using-some-kind-of-re

Comment: @pylearner - It is not easy for me, because my regex konwnedge is basic only. But you can add regex tag, pandas tag and your code, what you tre for avoid downvotes

Comment: any help on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751299/ignore-null-values-in-data-frame-and-build-a-new-data-frame-based-on-a-column