# How to Ignore Null values in data frame and build a new data frame based on a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I ignore null and None values in a data frame based on ID and frame the data.

```
id  A         B     C
A   []        []    []
A   [aaaa]   None   []
A   []      [bbbb]  None
A   []        []    [ccccc]
A   None      []    []
B   []        []    [zzzz]
B   []       None   []
B   [xxxx]   None   None
B   []        []    []
B   none    [yyyy]  None
```

can we re arrange the data set based on ID.

Output:

```
id  A   B   C
A   aaa bbb ccc
B   xxx yyy zzzz
```

Comment: Why do you command us? What is our question?

Comment: Edited the question..my bad.@DYZ

Comment: You do not have Null values. You have `None` values and empty lists. Neither are Nulls. Which of them do you want to ignore?

Comment: Can we ignore both of them ?so that I can fetch my value out of it. like the output shown in the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are `None` values like `NoneType` and lists in all another columns like `id`, then create index by `id`, get first values of lists by indexing with `str[0]`, replace `None`s to `NaN`s and last aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
print (df.applymap(type))
              id                   A                   B                   C
0  <class 'int'>      <class 'list'>      <class 'list'>      <class 'list'>
1  <class 'int'>      <class 'list'>  <class 'NoneType'>      <class 'list'>
2  <class 'int'>      <class 'list'>      <class 'list'>  <class 'NoneType'>
3  <class 'int'>      <class 'list'>      <class 'list'>      <class 'list'>
4  <class 'int'>  <class 'NoneType'>      <class 'list'>      <class 'list'>
5  <class 'int'>      <class 'list'>      <class 'list'>      <class 'list'>
6  <class 'int'>      <class 'list'>  <class 'NoneType'>      <class 'list'>
7  <class 'int'>      <class 'list'>  <class 'NoneType'>  <class 'NoneType'>
8  <class 'int'>      <class 'list'>      <class 'list'>      <class 'list'>
9  <class 'int'>  <class 'NoneType'>      <class 'list'>  <class 'NoneType'>
```

---

```
df1 = (df.set_index('id')
         .apply(lambda x: x.str[0]).mask(lambda x: x.isna(), np.nan)
         .groupby('id')
         .first())
print (df1)
       A     B      C
id                   
1   aaaa  bbbb  ccccc
2   xxxx  yyyy   zzzz
```

Another idea:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('id')
         .applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x == [] else x)
         .stack()
         .unstack()
         .apply(lambda x: x.str[0])
       )
print (df1)
       A     B      C
id                   
1   aaaa  bbbb  ccccc
2   xxxx  yyyy   zzzz
```

Comment: what If my `id` has string values ?

Comment: @pylearner - It working too, important is A,B, C columns Nonetype and lists

Comment: @pylearner - Can you be more specific? Best is add new column to input data and add expected output

Comment: Am creating a new question..gimme a min

Comment: this one is a bit complicated I feel ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751811/how-to-reframe-the-dataset-based-on-id-ignoring-the-null-and-empty-lists

Comment: I hope you understood the question, else I can reframe the question for your understanding.

Comment: @pylearner - Sure, working on it. Btw, for avoid downvotes add some code, what you try.