# How to reframe the dataset based on Id ignoring the null and empty lists

Tags: python, pandas

How can I reframe the dataset  based on column ID.

```
   id   time    A   B   C   D
A   11111   []  []  []  None
A   22222   [aaaa]  None    []  []
A   33333   []  []  [ccccc] sasasasasa
A   44444   None    None    []  ddfdfdf
A   55555   []  []  []  []
A   66666   []  [aaaa]  []  None
A   77777   [a1a1a1]    []  None    []
A   88888   None    []  []  None
A   99999   []  []  None    ssdskd
A   100000  []  []  []  sdsdsd
A   101111  None    [a1a1a1]    []  []
B   120000  [xxxx]  []  None    []
B   333333  []  None    []  []
B   130000      None    None    []
B   443430  []  []  [zzzz]  []
B   543434  none    [xxxx]  None    None
```

Based on the time column can we rearrange the dataset  as below

```
 ID data A  data B  A   B   c   D
A   22222   44444   aaaa    aaaa    ccccc   sasasasasa,ddfdfdf
A   55555   77777   a1a1a1  a1a1a1  nan ssdskd , sdsdsd
B   120000  130000  xxxx    xxxx    zzzz    nan
```

here column `data A` is the time when `column A` has appeared and `data B` is when time `column B` has appeared. `Column C` will always appear between `A` and `B`.

Code :

```
df1 = (df.set_index('id')
         .applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x == [] else x)
         .stack()
         .unstack()
         .apply(lambda x: x.str[0])
       )
```

Comment: Please revisit the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You've missed the part where you post your attempt at the solution as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  "Teach me how to do this in Python" is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part solution is similar - created `MultiIndex` by both columns, replaced empty lists to missing values, reshaped by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), removed ene element lists to scalars by indexing and convert time level of `MultiIndex` to column:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['id','time'])
         .applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x == [] else x)
         .stack()
         .str[0]
         .reset_index(level=1, name='new')
       )
print (df1)
        time     new
id                  
A  A   22222    aaaa
   C   33333   ccccc
   B   44444    aaaa
   A   55555  a1a1a1
   B   77777  a1a1a1
B  A  120000    xxxx
   C  333333    zzzz
   B  130000    xxxx
```

Then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), only is necessary deduplicate `MultiIndex` by new level with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then flatten columns with `join` for no `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df1 = (df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount(), append=True)
          .unstack(1)
          .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
          .rename(columns={'time':'data'}, level=0))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  id    data_A    data_B    data_C   new_A   new_B  new_C
0  A   22222.0   44444.0   33333.0    aaaa    aaaa  ccccc
1  A   55555.0   77777.0       NaN  a1a1a1  a1a1a1    NaN
2  B  120000.0  130000.0  333333.0    xxxx    xxxx   zzzz
```

EDIT: Solution is modify with aggregation first and `join` if duplicated consecutive values, here in column `D`, but it seems somt typo in data, because `data` columns created from `time` column not match:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['id','time'])
         .applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x == [] else x)
         .stack()
         .astype(str)
         .str.strip("[']")
         .reset_index(name='new')
         .rename(columns={'level_2':'cols'})
       )
df1['g'] = df1['cols'].ne(df1.groupby('id')['cols'].shift()).cumsum()
df1 = (df1.groupby(['id','cols', 'g'])
          .agg({'time':'first', 'new': ', '.join})
          .reset_index(level=2, drop=True))
print (df1)
           time                  new
id cols                             
A  A      22222                 aaaa
   A      77777               a1a1a1
   B      66666                 aaaa
   B     101111               a1a1a1
   C      33333                ccccc
   D      33333  sasasasasa, ddfdfdf
   D      99999       ssdskd, sdsdsd
B  A     120000                 xxxx
   B     543434                 xxxx
   C     443430                 zzzz
```

---

```
df1 = (df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount(), append=True)
          .unstack(1)
          .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
          .rename(columns={'time':'data'}, level=0))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  id    data_A    data_B    data_C   data_D   new_A   new_B  new_C  \
0  A   22222.0   66666.0   33333.0  33333.0    aaaa    aaaa  ccccc   
1  A   77777.0  101111.0       NaN  99999.0  a1a1a1  a1a1a1    NaN   
2  B  120000.0  543434.0  443430.0      NaN    xxxx    xxxx   zzzz   

                 new_D  
0  sasasasasa, ddfdfdf  
1       ssdskd, sdsdsd  
2                  NaN
```

Comment: how can I exclude data_c column ? not just by dropping it.

Comment: @pylearner Can you be more specific? Not working `df1 = df1.drop('data_C', axis=1)` ?

Comment: Can you also print me your dataframe ?

Comment: Yea the input dataset `print(df)` @jezrael

Comment: @pylearner - `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'time': [11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999, 100000, 101111, 120000, 333333, 130000], 'A': [[], ['aaaa'], [], [], ['a1a1a1'], None, [], [], None, [], [], ['xxxx'], [], None], 'B': [[], None, [], ['aaaa'], [], [], ['a1a1a1'], [], [], [], None, None, [], ['xxxx']], 'C': [[], [], ['ccccc'], [], None, [], None, [], [], None, [], None, ['zzzz'], None]})`

Comment: Hi @jezrael, am trying to add another column inplace, could you please help me in. Editing the same question

Comment: @pylearner - OK, please modify `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'time': [11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999, 100000, 101111, 120000, 333333, 130000], 'A': [[], ['aaaa'], [], [], ['a1a1a1'], None, [], [], None, [], [], ['xxxx'], [], None], 'B': [[], None, [], ['aaaa'], [], [], ['a1a1a1'], [], [], [], None, None, [], ['xxxx']], 'C': [[], [], ['ccccc'], [], None, [], None, [], [], None, [], None, ['zzzz'], None]})`

Comment: Modified the original input question, can you please go through it

Comment: @pylearner - Can you change `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'time': [11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999, 100000, 101111, 120000, 333333, 130000], 'A': [[], ['aaaa'], [], [], ['a1a1a1'], None, [], [], None, [], [], ['xxxx'], [], None], 'B': [[], None, [], ['aaaa'], [], [], ['a1a1a1'], [], [], [], None, None, [], ['xxxx']], 'C': [[], [], ['ccccc'], [], None, [], None, [], [], None, [], None, ['zzzz'], None]})` ?

Comment: Changed `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'time': [11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999, 100000, 101111, 120000, 333333, 130000], 'A': [[], ['aaaa'], [], [], ['a1a1a1'], None, [], [], None, [], [], ['xxxx'], [], None], 'B': [[], None, [], ['aaaa'], [], [], ['a1a1a1'], [], [], [], None, None, [], ['xxxx']], 'C': [[], [], ['ccccc'], [], None, [], None, [], [], None, [], None, ['zzzz'], None], 'D': [None, [], 'sasasasasa', 'ddfdfdf', [],None,[],None,'ssdskd','sdsdsd',[],[],[],[],[],None]})`

Comment: Sure, take your time. :)

Comment: @pylearner - answer was modify, but seems some typo in data (in comment, so failed run) and also data_A and data_B not match, because not clear whats happen if consecutive duplicates. So if not working please change sample data with expected output, thanks.